# Rails 4.2: redirect to remote URL fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this simple Rails app I'm working on and for the moment I want to redirect to another server remote URL.

In config/routes.rb I have:

```
  get "/adaptapp" => redirect(path: "https://exturl.com/adaptapp")
```

And **rake routes** gives:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
 welcome_index GET  /welcome/index(.:format) welcome#index
 adaptapp GET  /adaptapp(.:format)      redirect(301, path: 
                                https://exturl.com/adaptapp)
```

which to me look OK. But when I try it (*http://railsurl.com:3000/adaptapp*) I get an error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/https:/exturl.com/adaptapp"
```

What's going on? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of a URI is `scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]`

Having said, your syntax is yielding the correct response for the code you provided. What you want is `redirect("https://exturl.com/adaptapp")`

Comment: Thanks; I found the 'path:' param in another post but it must have referred to a previous version of Rails 4 (or I goofed, or both!)

Answer (score 0):

`get "/adaptapp" => redirect("https://exturl.com/adaptapp")`, `path` param makes your url relative.